Как спозиционировать правильно данные элементы элеенты с помощью Bootstrap или css?
Я столкнулся с проблемой при позиционировании элементов. Используя библиотеку Bootstrap я создал данную структуру:


<section class="reasons">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <h2 class="reasons__h2">8 причин начать работать с нами</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6 "></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6 "></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6 "></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="reasons__items col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



И у меня получилось вот что.

Но должно получится вот так:

Подскажите пожалуйста как спозиционировать данные элементы элементы? Может быть есть такие функции в Bootstrap, или какие css свойства можно применить?

мне кажется это курс и верстал по нему сайт такой же, посмотри просто дальше и сделай как там)

я бы сделал это так  в родительском блоке прописал
   display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

при этом поднял
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                    <h2 class="reasons__h2">8 причин начать работать с нами</h2>
</div>

на уровень выше
или так же если используется свойство
display: grid; вместо  display: flex;
то просто прописал
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

есть конечно множество способ как это сделать
